# set access-control-allow-origin response header only for static files in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I'm using **IIS** to serve static files and also to send API requests to a python backend server.
for API requests the backend correctly sets CORS-related headers but for static files, I get errors. additionally, I can't set these in Response Headers in **IIS** because it conflicts with those set with the backend app.
So is there any way in **IIS** to check if some certain header is empty or requested response is a file or even check URI for a pattern like `/static/` and then modify the response header?
I've reached to **URLRewrite** so far but I doubt it could modify the header.

Answer (score 0):

after a little bit of digging it turned out you can set **Response Header** specific to each directory. so I set the CORS-related headers in my `./static/` sub-directories and it works fine.